# Top and bottom margin moved

Tags: margins

I wonder if someone may know the answer to my problem.
Firstly, I had a list of figure issue beyond 100 and in this forum I was told to use this piece of code which work perfectly and I thank to this forum but

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{3.5em}
```

I realised later that the top and bottom margin of my document changed and I have tried a few things with no success.  Can any one help?  This is an example of my document :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

%%%%%figure beyond 100
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{3.5em}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{graphicx,rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}%for table decimals number
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{amssymb}%checkmark on table

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{\cfoot{\thepage}}}{\slshape \rightmark}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %lets the head rule disappear.
\lhead{\textbf{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}


\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[textfont=normalfont]{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\newcommand\apj{1925ApJ....61...38R}  % Journal abbreviations 
\addtolength{\topmargin}{.25in}  %topmargin control
%%%to use parenthesis in subfigure 1(a)
%\usepackage[caption=false,labelformat=simple]{subfig}
%\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\captionsetup [subfigure]{font=scriptsize}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  %to include subsection in table of cont.
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{roman}       %change page number style



\begin{document}

Here, the power density was varied by adjusting the position of the focussing lens using the motorised linear actuator.  The laser energy was kept fixed while the lens was moved to several positions from the focal point into the target.  The observed spectra showed that the relative intensity increased as the power density dropped as result of defocussing and the associated increase of the laser spot size (i.e. the size of the laser cone lead to greater emission of EUV photons).\\
Each of the four spectra above shared a similar spectral profile except for the lowest power density ($\phi$ = 3.93$\times$10$^{10}$) in the $Sn$, $W$ and $Pb$ spectra in which the spectral profile bear only resemblance at longer wavelengths.\\


Inverse Bremsstrahlung or free-free absorption, occurs when a photon is absorbed by an electron in the continuum.   In inverse B. during the collision with atom the electron absorbs a photon or a number of photons.  
The absorption of a photon by a free electron which gains kinetic energy due to the absorption.
Free electrons can absorb radiation in a non-resonant process called inverse-bremsstrahlung, only in the process of collision with heavy charged particles such as ions or atomic nuclei. The third particle, in this case ion/nucleus, is needed for energy and momentum conservation. Both cannot be conserved if only a photon interact with an electron. Not only one photon but also many photons can be emitted in one elementary act of scattering.  The process of the emission of more that one photon is called stimulated multiphoton bremsstrahlung.\\


Atomic processes in plasmas
The charged particles in the plasma interact strongly, with the most essential mechanisms
being excitation, relaxation, ionisation and recombination. In plasmas the
two main processes which take place are collisional and radiative but the importance
of each process varies with the type of plasma present, and also as the plasma
evolves. Collisional processes dominate at high plasma densities while at low
plasma densities, the ions in the plasma interact mainly through radiative processes.
The plasma density and the competition between collisional and radiative
mechanisms are important in determining the energy evolution of the plasma and
the ionisation balance within the plasma. Every atomic process occurring in the
plasma can be balanced by an equal and opposite process.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't change layout dimensions manually if using `geometry`. You are changing `\topmargin` behind `geometry`'s back. How is it supposed to keep track when you don't tell it you're messing with its calculations? Check the console, also, for warnings from `fancyhdr`. `fancyhdr` will change the margins if they are too small.

Comment: Looks funny: `\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{\cfoot{\thepage}}}{\slshape \rightmark}  `.

Comment: The console only warning is Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3--6

Comment: What's your suggestion? Not to use this:???/
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1cm]{geometry}

Comment: I still dont know how to solve it, any help?

Comment: No, I'd stick with geometry, but tell it all the relevant changes you want. Your example is not very minimal. Try removing things until you figure out the source of the issue.

Comment: I don't really see what's wrong with the output. You should not use `\\ ` to end lines outside special contexts such as `tabular`. That's probably responsible for the bad boxes.

Comment: Use `parskip` if you want to use vertical space to separate paragraphs rather than an indent. Absolutely do not try to add space using `\\ `.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62998/discussion-between-yoyo-and-cfr).

Comment: The problem is that since I started using \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{3.5em}
\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{3.5em} My top and margin of the page has become smaller. how can i solve it?

Comment: I am new in latex so I do not really understand too technical answers.

Comment: Removing those lines makes no difference to the output when compiling the example.

Comment: so what is the best solution?

Comment: You are making me confused with all your comments. Please stick to the initial problem. how to control the top and bottom margin from the code I provided above

Comment: Solution to what? Adding or removing those lines makes no difference to the output. The margins don't change. You need to provide an example which demonstrates the problem. That is, when the example is compiled with those lines, the result should be different from that obtained when the example is compiled without those lines. Otherwise, there is no problem to solve.

Comment: the problem is that when i started to use that piece of code, it solved the list of figure beyond 100 problem i was facing but the top and bottom margin got smaller. that is the main problem.

Comment: ***Your example does not demonstrate the problem.*** It is very unlikely anybody will be able to help you without an example of the problem.